Is railing (as in fence) always used in the plural form in American English?
The observation I have made is that native speaker say railings instead of just railing even though the entire fence-like structure running along the edges of let's say a deck is a single unit or when there is a railing on each side of a bridge and those railings aren't even connected, native speakers say railings instead of railing when referring to solely the fence-like structure on, let's say, the right side of the bridge.

You've got it backwards! I always use singular in contexts like He leaned over the railing. But actually, comparing British usage and American usage over the past 50 years it seems preference for singular is far stronger in AmE than BrE.

I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misconception

Metal railings are not always sold in one piece. In the past, sections were often welded together, so speaking about (iron) railings, the traditional kind, makes sense. US YouTube clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRn4NVEJOy0

The thing around a deck in AmE would be a railing, no s. So I have no idea where you got that plural idea from.

OED doesn't list it as American English:

2.d. In plural. A fence or barrier made of upright posts and horizontal rails; (also occasionally in singular) a rail-post.

People in the area say children often climb over the railings to play on the land.
Evening Chronicle (Newcastle) (Nexis) 3 October 11


Collins even labels it as British English:

railings 
in British English 
plural noun
a fence, balustrade, or barrier that consists of rails supported by posts

This Ngram shows that in both AmE and BrE, the use of railings is in decline, but it is more common in BrE:


Ngrams may be misleading, since it includes the -ing form of the verb "to rail".

I'm not American, but I would use railings for a barrier made of multiple metal uprights, close together and linked at or near the top and sometimes near the bottom as well.
A railing is what I would call a horizontal bar supported by uprights at intervals, either set in the ground/floor or running along the top of a wall.

I think I agree, Kate. But a reference?

I don't see the difference between one and two.

@Lambie - Railings. A safety railing. Admittedly there isn't a hard and fast distinction, but that's how I think of it. Railings are to mark a boundary, a railing is to stop you falling off something or to help you climb steps.

Ok, so railings as a general definition versus railing as a structure around one thing. I see no AmE-BrE difference here at all.
